# How to navigate to a bookmark in eclipse 3.4.1?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, bookmarks

I am able to set bookmarks in a source file, but are there shortcut keys to navigate to a bookmark ? The **navigate** menu has a goto line. But that is not useful.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is not a shortcut key but you can make appear a 'Bookmark view' which is located in *Window > Show view > Other...* and in the dialog inside the *General* classification, Then just double-click on the desired bookmark to reach it

Comment: Cool. At least I can still go to the bookmark view via CTRL+SHIFT+F7

Answer (score 52):

If you check the "Bookmark" item in the "Next Annotation"/"Previous Annotation" toolbar dropdown item, you can use `Ctrl+,` and `Ctrl+.` to navigate to previous/next bookmark in the current opened file.

[image: toolbar]

from [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#sourcenavigation_annotations)

Comment: This answer works well, but I misinterpreted it at first. I wrongly thought that it meant to press Ctrl and then the plus sign. I thought the comma and the full stop (or period for our US friends) were there for punctuation! Of course, pressing Ctrl then comma or the full stop makes perfect sense, because it allows you to navigate up and down a file in an entirely familiar way. As you would normally do for warnings and errors.

Answer (score 6):

You can navigate to bookmarks using a plugin like:

http://www.etc.to/eclipse_bookmarks_plugin

Comment: New location for the plugin: http://domui.org/wiki/bin/view/Documentation/EclipsePlugin

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Quick Bookmarks Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-bookmarks-plugin#.U9p6nEThGlM) which is very handy;

You can create named bookmarks using digits (e.g., 1 to 9):

Example:

> Set bookmark #4 with [Alt+4]
>
> Go to bookmark #4 with [Alt+Shift+4]

and so on.

Comment: The link to Quick Bookmarks is now dead - anybody know of an update?

Answer (score -1):

ctrl f2 will create a booksmark
shift f2 will navigate through all bookmarks
I using eclipse with build id: 20130919-0819

Hope it helps

Comment: In my Eclipse, Ctrl+F2 does nothing, Shift+F2 does something completely different (related to Javadoc, see [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseShortcuts/article.html)).