# Show only python function def in PyDev Eclipse/Aptana

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, aptana, outline-view

Is there a way in a huge python file , you just see the function def you are interested in ? I remember Eclipse has an option to do this in Java and it was pretty helpful.How about for Python in PyDev/Aptana Studio 3?

Comment: Yes , but such that in window you just have that function not others when you scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use the regular outline (Alt+Shift+Q O) with a filter.

In case you can't really make a filter with just the functions you want, you can add comments to your code in the format: "#--- comment" and those comments should then appear in the outline and then do a filter that leaves only those comments available.

[image: Outline filter with comments]

Note that sometimes the quick outline is already good enough (Ctrl+O), but it currently doesn't show those comments as the regular outline.

Another solution could be using bookmarks -- ctrl+F10, add bookmark -- there are tips for using the bookmarks properly at: [How to navigate to a bookmark in eclipse 3.4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949440/how-to-navigate-to-a-bookmark-in-eclipse-3-4-1)

Answer (score 2):

Look in Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Code Folding. Enable Folding for Function Definitions. Then hit `Ctrl-9` and `Ctrl-0` to fold and unfold your code.

Edit: You can also use `Ctrl--` (minus) and `Ctrl-=` to fold and unfold single levels.

Comment: Thanks.But this folds and unfolds all the definitions.I just want to unfold and view one.I know I can hit + in the bar right int the frame , but there was a way that you could hide all others.So you could just browse that special function of your interest.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to "fold everything else", but you can hit `Ctrl-9` then `Ctrl-=` on your definition to show only that one.